# What is this LEGO part number? Technic, right angle with 4 pins sticking out

Tags: part-identification, technic

This part is required for building a LEGO steering rack. It connects the moving rack to the wheel axle.

[image: Technic, right angle with 4 pins sticking out]

Comment: Building a steering rack might be the usage you have seen, but you can build steering racks without this part and this part has other uses (I don't even remember seeing it used for steering racks).

Comment: Check if you are referencing correct part. Usually, [Technic, Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with 4 Pins
](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48989) is used for steering rack you ar elooking to assemble as this piece has all 4 pins in parallel which help constructing steering links.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful advice. You guys are great!  Actually this is where I found someone using this piece for a rack and pinion steering. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZIkTLrnLKw

Answer (score 9):

On Bricklink, that's called [Technic, Pin Connector Perpendicular 3 x 3 Bent with 4 Pins.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55615)

[image: connector]

It has known design IDs 55615 and 49130. And in Light Bluish Gray has item numbers 4296059 and 6313453.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have now been able to locate it on ebay.